# How to bypass Element Tree mismatched tag error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, elementtree

So just a bit of context, I'm currently using Element Tree to scrape several crypto news feeds for the latest article headlines. The code below works for most sites, however in some feeds I'm getting the following error for example:

xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 134, column 2

I'm guessing this is due to an error in the XML code for that website. I'm looking for a way to bypass this error and to pull the last headline regardless, would appreciate some help on this :)
Code below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests

r = requests.get('https://cointelegraph.com/feed')
root = ET.fromstring(r.text)

headline = root.find('channel/item/title').text


print(headline)
```

Comment: IIRC, BeautifulSoup is more forgiving of malformed xml if you specify 'html.parser'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting Cloudflare captcha page. Try to specify `User-Agent` in HTTP headers:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
}
r = requests.get("https://cointelegraph.com/feed", headers=headers)
root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
headline = root.find("channel/item/title").text
print(headline)
```

Prints:

```
Why is XRP seeing a monster rally when Ripple is worth just $3B on the secondary market?
```